# slice vs array for data of known length

Tags: arrays, go, slice

When dealing with something like a `sha256` hash which has a known length of 32 bytes– is it more idiomatic to work with `[]byte` slices or `[32]byte` arrays?

I'm a bit new to go– but intuitively it feels like while working with a `[32]byte` array to store a hash is nice and explicit, it's actually quite cumbersome to manipulate and requires all sorts of strange things like copying the array into a new buffer slice to manipulate as `[]byte`.

Comment: You can get a slice of an array without copying: `a[:]`

Comment: That's exactly what `a[:]` does, It converts an array to a slice (without copying)

Comment: @ChrisDrew sorry– I was saying this part backwards the whole time. I mean a slice to an array.

Comment: Remember that if an owner holds an array and then this is converted to a slice and the values are modified then this also modifies the values in the original array. So you often don't have to convert a slice to an array. But if you do, yes you will have to copy, e.g `copy(a[:], s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Go standard library, it looks like arrays are often used for something like a hash of known length. e.g [sha256.Sum256](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/#Sum256) returns a `[sha256.Size]byte` where [`sha256.Size`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/sha256/#pkg-constants) is 32. Or looking at the [`digest`](https://golang.org/src/crypto/sha256/sha256.go#L50) struct that implements the `hash.Hash` interface in `sha256` it contains `[chunk]byte` where `chunk` is 64, the sha256 blocksize.

I think it is typical to use arrays to avoid unnecessary memory allocation. To take advantage of algorithms that operate on slices of a variable length you can convert the array to a slice without copying with `x[:]`.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
)

type myHash struct {
    x [32]byte
}

func print(b []byte) {
    fmt.Print(b)
}

func main() {
    b := []byte("Hello world!")
    h := myHash{x: sha256.Sum256(b)}
    print(h.x[:])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slices are first class in Go and seem to be the preferred way based on their compared usage to arrays in the standard library.

Converting an array to a slice is straitforward as well:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    array := [5]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    slice := array[:]
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground", array, slice)
}
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of slices of a fixed length being used in the standard library?